# How to Create ItemTemplate of ListPicker

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

In following http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth I am trying to set my ListPicker to be populated using a List of custom class type, but for some reason I do not see my items bound in the view. What I have is

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="SearchProviderItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Favicon}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="SearchProviderFullModeItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Favicon}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

...

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="SearchProviderListPicker" 
                            Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_SearchProvider, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" ItemTemplate="{Binding SearchProviderItemTemplate}"
                            FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_SearchProvider, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding SearchProviderFullModeItemTemplate}"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding}"
                            SelectionChanged="SearchProviderListPicker_SelectionChanged" 
                            CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
List<ListItem> searchProviderList;

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PopulateSearchProviderList();
    }

    private void PopulateSearchProviderList()
    {
        searchProviderList = new List<ListItem>();

        searchProviderList.Add(new ListItem { Favicon = "", Name = "Bing", Address = "http://www.bing.com" });
        searchProviderList.Add(new ListItem { Favicon = "", Name = "Google", Address = "http://www.google.com" });

        SearchProviderListPicker.ItemsSource = searchProviderList;
    }
```

For some reason all I see in the ListPicker is `TestApp.Classes.ListItem`. The class `ListItem` I created is simply the following

ListItem.cs

```
public string Favicon
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: ItemTemplate="{StaticRessource yourDataTemplate}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="SearchProviderListPicker" 
                        Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_SearchProvider, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" ItemTemplate="{Binding SearchProviderItemTemplate}"
                        FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_SearchProvider, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding SearchProviderFullModeItemTemplate}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding}"
                        SelectionChanged="SearchProviderListPicker_SelectionChanged" 
                        CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
```

to this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="SearchProviderListPicker" 
                        Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_SearchProvider, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchProviderItemTemplate}"
                        FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_SearchProvider, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                        FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchProviderFullModeItemTemplate}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding}"
                        SelectionChanged="SearchProviderListPicker_SelectionChanged" 
                        CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
```

Comment: I can't tell what the difference is between the original and the updated version?

Comment: {StaticResource instead of {Binding when assigning Templates